# Sleep Connection in MySql for long time leads to Slow process in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate

I am using Hibernate in my application,

My connection code is as follows,

```
public class DBConnection{

    private static SessionFactory factory; 
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public  DBConnection()
       {
        try
          { 
                      factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

          }
          catch (Throwable ex) { 
                    System.err.println("Failed to create   sessionFactory object." + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
                }
       }

    public Session getSession() 
    {
          return factory.openSession();
    }


   // Call this during shutdown
  public static void close() {
        factory.close();
        serviceRegistry=null;
        factory=null;

   }
}
```

My Hibernate config file is ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>


   <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect">
      org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
      com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

   </property>

   <!-- Assume test is the database name -->
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/Test
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
      root
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root
   </property>
     <property name=" hibernate.dbcp.max Wait">100</property>
</session-factory>


</hibernate-configuration>
```

The sample code for this process is

```
 public String showurl(int id)
    {
        int i = 1;
        String url= "";
        Transaction tx= null;
        Session session = null;
        try
        {
            session = new DBConnection().getSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            Query query = session.createQuery(" FROM Test WHERE ID = :id");
            query.setInteger("id", id);

            List<Test> testlist= query.list();
            for(Test nl:testlist)
            {
                url= nl.geturl();
            }


        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        DBConnection.close();


    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        if(tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        session.close();
        DBConnection.close();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(tx!=null)
        {
        tx=null;
        }
        if(session.isOpen())
        {
            session.close();
        }
        if(session!=null)
        {
            session= null;
        }
    }

        return url; 

    }
```

My problem here is , due to lot of sleep queries in the Database leads to slow down the process. How to solve this in my Application. I have more than 50 users using the application at the same time. how to solve this problem?

While Using this I am getting the following error frequently,

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]] with root cause
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatisticsImplementor(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1468)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getStatistics(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1464)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:346)
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start from using other connection pool manager than Hibernate's build-in one - It it not design for production use. Try to use [C3P0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/). [Here is little hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475893/what-are-the-required-c3p0-settings-for-hibernate-in-order-to-avoid-deadlocks) how to configure it for hibernate. More informations can be found [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToConfigureTheC3P0ConnectionPool)

**EDIT:**
I have just noticed, that you are creating new session factory everytime you want to operate od db. That is SO **WRONG!** You should have only **ONE** instance of session factory, as service or application scope static field, and later use that for creating sessions as needed.

```
 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
     if (factory == null) {

         try {
             factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

         } catch (Throwable ex) {
             System.err.println("Failed to create   sessionFactory object." + ex);
             throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
         }
     }
     return factory;

 }

 public static Session getSession() {
     return getSessionFactory().openSession();
 }
```

from code use `getSession()` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your Response. Now i am getting the following error frequently(Edited in the Question). could you please suggest me how to avoid this?

Comment: Thank you for the info. I couldn't get your point. Could you please elaborate or guide me through an example?

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. I tried this in my server, again  I am getting the  following error,  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]] with root cause
org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.stat.spi.StatisticsImplementor]