# Not able to connect with database after some times of deployment on server

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

I uploaded my war file on my server it works perfectly after deploy but after some time it shows exception.
I am using struts2 and hibernate

my `hibernate.cfg.xml` is

```xml
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">UserName</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">Password</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">round</property>  
    <property name="autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="maxIdleTime">0</property>
    <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property> 
</session-factory>
```

On console After executing query it is showing following `Exception`

```
263512233 [http-bio-12414-exec-1768] WARN org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
263512233 [http-bio-12414-exec-1768] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2545)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at iland.login.LoginBusiness.HbmLogin(LoginBusiness.java:104)
    at iland.login.LoginAction.doLogin(LoginAction.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.Connection was implicitly closed by the driver.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:382)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1013)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1213)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1200)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4203)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4169)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1700)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 102,104,208 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 102,104,208 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:407)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3348)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1967)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2626)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2111)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3329)
    ... 87 more
Hibernate: 
    /* insert iland.hbm.ErrorLog
        */ insert 
        into
            xrcwrn_retail_shop.error_log
            (class, method, line_no, error, add_date) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Aug 19, 2014 5:23:08 AM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.commons.CommonsLogger error
SEVERE: Exception occurred during processing request: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at iland.login.LoginBusiness.LoginSessionSave(LoginBusiness.java:123)
    at iland.login.LoginBusiness.HbmLogin(LoginBusiness.java:116)
    at iland.login.LoginAction.doLogin(LoginAction.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How to resolve above problem.
So that it can work properly all the time.

Edit: After few hours of deployment it is showing above problem. On my server I am using Apache Tomcat 7 and my sql database.

New Addition:
  Added following details

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">0</property>
```

Still facing the problem what modification/addition should I make here

Comment: Use a connection pool.

Comment: You definitely need a Database connection pooling.  Please try [this link][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7621207/1069633

Comment: Can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850585/how-to-start-spring-boot-app-without-depending-on-database? I think it will help you as this page eventually explains the settings required to set up the database connection on the fly whenever required.

Answer (score 7):

In your configuration properties you have used c3p0 property `maxIdleTime`, but c3p0 properties are configured using `c3p0.` prefix or `hibernate.c3p0.`. Note that enabling any of `c3p0` properties automatically enables the corresponding connection provider by Hibernate heuristics. In the log isn't seen that you are using c3p0. If you are not configured data sources then Hibernate will use

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class = org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider
```

This connection provider has in-built rudimentary connection pool for which you can set a `hibernate.connection.pool_size`, but it is used only for development purposes. Never use it in the production environment.

You might have endless discussion on topic [How to fix `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2309561/573032). After some time you will realize that you have remained *open* connections in the pool, which are suddenly closed on the other side by the following reasons:

- Firewalls or routers may clamp down on idle connections (the MySQL client/server protocol does not
  ping).
- The MySQL Server may be closing idle connections that exceed the `wait_timeout` or
  `interactive_timeout` threshold.

To help troubleshoot these issues, the following tips can be used:

- A recent (5.1.13+) version of JDBC driver is used.
- Ensure that `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` are set sufficiently high. Check if `interactiveClient` is used.
- Ensure that `tcpKeepalive` is enabled.
- Ensure that any configurable firewall or router timeout settings allow for the maximum expected connection idle time.
- Ensure connections are valid when used from the connection pool. Use a query that starts with `/* ping */` to execute a lightweight ping instead of full query. Note, the syntax of the ping needs to be exactly as specified here.
- Explicitly validate the connection before using it if the connection has been left idle for an extended period of time.
- Minimize the duration a connection object is left idle while other application logic is executed.

To comply to some of this options you'd better use a connection pool that you can use with Hibernate. Hibernate has support for commons-dbcp, c3p0, and proxool. Also you can configure JNDI data source on web server to use with hibernate, it has a connection pool. See [Chapter 7 Connection Pooling with Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html).

If you like to configure Hibernate with c3p0 you should read this

> ## [How-To configure the C3P0 connection pool](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-14014)
>
> Configuration
> Here is a sample of C3P0 configuration. This is an extract of hibernate.cfg.xml:
>
> ```xml
> <!-- configuration pool via c3p0--> 
> <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property> 
> <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property> <!-- seconds --> 
> <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property> 
> <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property> 
> <property name="c3p0.min_size">10</property> 
> <property name="c3p0.timeout">100</property> <!-- seconds --> 
> <!-- DEPRECATED very expensive property name="c3p0.validate>-->
> ```
>
> You also can set extra c3p0 properties using c3p0.properties. Put this file in the classpath (WEB-INF/classes for example), but be careful, the previous values will be overridden by Hibernate whether set or not (see below for more details). For more information on C3P0 configuration, please have a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0 and unzip the download, there is a doc folder where you'll find everything you need.
>
> For more on hibernate/c3p0 issues, see c3p0's docs at http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#appendix_d
>
> Parameters
> c3p0 is very tunable, and offers a somewhat bewildering array of configuration parameters. For the complete list, see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#appendix_a
>
> Here are a subset of the most important features:
>
> `initialPoolSize` C3P0 default: 3
>
> `minPoolSize` Must be set in hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties), Hibernate default: 1
>
> `maxPoolSize` Must be set in hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties), Hibernate default: 100
>
> `idleTestPeriod` Must be set in hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties), Hibernate default: 0
>
> If this is a number greater than 0, c3p0 will test all idle, pooled but unchecked-out connections, every this number of seconds.
>
> `timeout` Must be set in hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties), Hibernate default: 0
>
> The seconds a Connection can remain pooled but unused before being discarded. Zero means idle connections never expire.
>
> `maxStatements` Must be set in hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties), Hibernate default: 0
>
> The size of c3p0's PreparedStatement cache. Zero means statement caching is turned off.
>
> `propertyCycle` Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: 300
>
> Maximum time in seconds before user configuration constraints are enforced. c3p0 enforces configuration constraints continually, and ignores this parameter. It is included for JDBC3 completeness.
>
> `acquireIncrement` Must be set in hibernate.cfg.xml (or hibernate.properties), Hibernate default: 1
>
> Determines how many connections at a time c3p0 will try to acquire when the pool is exhausted.
>
> `testConnectionOnCheckout` Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: false
>
> Don't use it, this feature is very expensive. If set to true, an operation will be performed at every connection checkout to verify that the connection is valid. A better choice is to verify connections periodically using c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod.
>
> `autoCommitOnClose` Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: false
>
> The JDBC spec is unfortunately silent on what should happen to unresolved, pending transactions on Connection close. C3P0's default policy is to rollback any uncommitted, pending work. (I think this is absolutely, undeniably the right policy, but there is no consensus among JDBC driver vendors.) Setting autoCommitOnClose to true causes uncommitted pending work to be committed, rather than rolled back on Connection close. [Note: Since the spec is absurdly unclear on this question, application authors who wish to avoid bugs and inconsistent behavior should ensure that all transactions are explicitly either committed or rolled-back before close is called.]
>
> `forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions` Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: false
>
> Strongly disrecommended. Setting this to true may lead to subtle and bizarre bugs. This is a terrible setting, leave it alone unless absolutely necessary. It is here to work around broken databases / JDBC drivers that do not properly support transactions, but that allow Connections' autoCommit flags to be set to false regardless. If you are using a database that supports transactions "partially" (this is oxymoronic, as the whole point of transactions is to perform operations reliably and completely, but nevertheless, such databases exist), if you feel comfortable ignoring the fact that Connections with autoCommit == false may be in the middle of transactions and may hold locks and other resources, you may turn off c3p0's wise default behavior, which is to protect itself, as well as the usability and consistency of the database, by either rolling back (default) or committing (see c3p0.autoCommitOnClose above) unresolved transactions. This should only be set to true when you are sure you are using a database that allows Connections' autoCommit flag to go to false, but that it offers no other meaningful support of transactions. Otherwise setting this to true is just a bad idea.
>
> `numHelperThreads` Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: 3
>
> c3p0 is very asynchronous. Slow JDBC operations are generally performed by helper threads that don't hold contended locks. Spreading these operations over multiple threads can significantly improve performance by allowing multiple operations to be performed simultaneously.
>
> `factoryClassLocation` Must be set in c3p0.properties, C3P0 default: null
>
> DataSources that will be bound by JNDI and use that API's Referenceable interface to store themselves may specify a URL from which the class capable of dereferencing a them may be loaded. If (as is usually the case) the c3p0 libraries will be locally available to the JNDI service, leave this set to null.

---

For dbcp example configuration you should check this post

> ## [MySQL, Hibernate and Broken Pipe Exception](https://amitcodes.wordpress.com/2008/07/26/16/)
>
> I was using Hibernate with Apache Tomcat and MySQL with apache-commons-dbcp for a web application I was developping recently and I used to get this annoying `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe` after about 8 hours of usage. I tried the following quick fixes:
>
> sessions were closed (which acually were)
> ensuring that the MySQL connection URL had autoreconnect=true attribute
> But none of it fixed the issue. Finally after searching for a while on internet I found out the cause and here it is.
>
> Cause: MySQL server has a default timeout period after which it terminates the idle connections. This period is 8 hours by default. Now here’s what happens. The dbcp creates a set of connections to database when the servlet container / application server starts up. If the connections are not used for the tinmeout period, the MySQL server assumes these to be dead connections and terminates them. The dbcp, however, is unaware of the fact that the connections have been terminated. So when a connection is demended from the connection-pool, these dead connections are returned and when a call is made on these dead connections – *BOOM* – you the `java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe exception`. Ok – so what’s the fix ??
>
> Fix: If only the connection pool could check if the the connection it is about to return is live or not, the porblem is fixed. This can be done in apache-common-dbcp (I know this one coz I used it, please look into documentation of the connection-pool you are using). Here’s how you do it: You add the following properties to dbcp configuration.
>
> ```
> validationQuery=”SELECT 1″
> testOnBorrow=”true”
> ```
>
> And that does the trick.
>
> How it works:
>
> Before returning the connection from pool to the application, dbcp runs the `“SELECT 1 ”` query on the connection to see it it is still live. That’s the job of `validationQuery`.
> As for `testOnBorrow`, you tell dbcp to perform the check before returning the connection to application.
>
> For more details refer to the apache-common-dbcp configuration manual [here](https://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html). The apache-commons-dbcp config:
>
> ```xml
> <Resource  name="jdbc/cooldatabase"
>            description="Strandls.com license database"
>            auth="Container"
>            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
>            factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
>            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
>            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cooldatabase?autoReconnect=true"
>            username="cooluser"
>            password="coolpassword"
>            initialSize="0"
>            maxActive="20"
>            maxIdle="10"
>            minIdle="0"
>            maxWait="-1"
>            validationQuery="SELECT 1"
>            testOnBorrow="true"
>            poolPreparedStatements="true"
>            removeAbandoned="true"
>            removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
>            logAbandoned="true"/>
> ```

---

Whatever connection pooling you will use is up to you.

Comment: Added few paramenters please see what extra should i add there

Comment: Check [these](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing) parameters.

Comment: You should accept this answer.

Answer (score 3):

What server are you using? Are you hosting on a cloud platform as a service such as OpenShift?

Usually for free plans, your site will spin down after idling for a while. When accessed again after some time, the web server spins up the fastest, but the database server spins up slower, causing the connection error. Usually just refreshing the page a few times will wake everything up and be good to go.

https://www.openshift.com/products/pricing under "Gear idling"

Update: if you are running on your own server,

Change this line to the following for a quick fix

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName?autoReconnect=true</property>
```

See this question for better understanding

[com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565143/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-mysqlnontransientconnectionexception-no-operati)

Comment: No my own server it users Apache tomcat 7.0.22.                         My another application is workin properly it uses jdbc code it does not give any problem.

Comment: I have modified the answer and I think that will solve your issue.

Comment: I have mentioned `<property name="autoReconnect">true</property>` is it not a effective way

Comment: Sry didn't see that you already have that option set. Try the connection pooling method that I mentioned in the link. It should be the best way to keep an active connection.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occurring because your app is leaving the connections open for too long and something is timing them out.  One of three things is timing out the connection:

1. A firewall between the app server and database server
2. The database server OS
3. The database engine

Have you considered setting maxIdleTime to a non-zero value or configuring Hibernate to use a [connection pool](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) that can periodically test the connections (thereby keeping the TCP connection open) or [discard them after they have been open for a certain period of time](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#maxIdleTime)?

Comment: I used `<property name="maxIdleTime">0</property>` which represent infinite time to idle

Answer (score 1):

You have to configure your idle time and configure a connection pool too, i will recommend  c3p0

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-the-c3p0-connection-pool-in-hibernate/

Also you can fin here the basic of how to configure parameters and how it works

[What are the required C3P0 settings for hibernate in order to avoid Deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475893/what-are-the-required-c3p0-settings-for-hibernate-in-order-to-avoid-deadlocks)

In some cases when you "modify" your app from outside those errors may occur

Comment: Added as ypur suggestion what extra should do here

Comment: You have to set your parameters
"hibernate.c3p0.min_size" This is the minimum number of JDBC connections that C3P0 keeps ready at all times.
"hibernate.c3p0.max_size" This is the maximum number of connections in the pool.

And as thomas said;
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_periods must not be higher than hibernate.c3p0.timeout

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3731978/3509166

Comment: and please try not to edit/modify your project while running. also try a "fresh" start... i mean stop services and recompile the project.. then run/start all again